# How can I set the VS Code terminal panel width to span the entire window?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've been reading the [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/appearance) but couldn't find anything on the *width* of the terminal pane. Currently the pane is situated like so:
[image]

How do I make it span the complete window all to the left side of the main Visual Studio Code window?

I did search here and found questions and answers on the height but not on the width of the pane. Either the docs don´t mention it, or I've missed it.

Comment: Rightclick on the invisible bar containing "PROBLEMS","OUTPUT",... Then from the appeared dropdown select "Align panel > left"

Comment: @Cosemuckel Thanks so much. This is indeed missing from the documentation. I will see if I can add that.

Answer (score 2):

Right click the panel's "title" bar (it's called that in the code even though there's no text there) (the middle part of the top bar of the panel between the tab handles (left) and the action menu (right)), open the "Align Panel" sub-menu, and then select "Left" (the default is "Center").

As for mentions of this in the docs, see https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_64#_panel-alignment (the problem is just knowing the right terminology to search for).

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I agree I did not go through all the release notes but it is not very likely someone else would (present company excepted no doubt) so in my humble opinion it still would be rather helpful in the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs).

Comment: @theking2 you can [raise an issue ticket](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/issues/new) or a Pull Request. If you do, please comment here with a link to it.

Comment: Update request : https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/issues/6239